# Junit : Trigger concurrent method calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, concurrentmodification

The objective is to have a unit test to test the concurrent modification exception issue of ArrayList in a method customerservice.registry(). I have to trigger this method concurrently to simulate this.

**Actual Method in the CustomerService Class** :

```
List<Customer> customerData = Lists.newArrayList();
public synchronized void registry(){
....
}
```

---

**Unit Test** :

```
public class concurrencyTest {
    ......

    @Test
    public void concurrency() throws InterruptedException {
        int numberOfThreads = 100;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numberOfThreads);
        AtomicBoolean terminate = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            service.execute(() -> {
                while (!terminate.get()) {
                    try {
                        customerservice.registry(CustomerData.class);
                    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                        endExecution.set(true);
                    }
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            });
        }
        latch.await();
        assertEquals(terminate.get, false);
    }
}
```

---

The Unit test as mentioned above is the right approach to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

> The objective is to have a unit test to test the concurrent modification exception issue of ArrayList in a method customerservice.registry(). I have to trigger this method concurrently to simulate this.

This is incorrect. There is no need to involve more than one thread. The *concurrent* in `ConcurrentModificationException` doesn't mean what you think it means. In fact, involving multiple threads is one of the few ways that you can make ConcurrentModificationException *not* occur. It gets in the way of testing it.

Here, run this. It'll throw CoModEx, every time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.of("A", "B", "C"));
  for (String y : list) if (y.equals("A")) list.add("Found!");
}
```

Trivial code, isn't it?

ConcurrentModificationException simply means that this sequence of events happened:

1. Some code made an iterator from `collection` (and note that `for (Type t : col)` does this)
2. Some code changes the collection, for example by adding something or removing something.
3. You interact with the iterator in any way.

There is no need to involve threads to do this - see the above code, where we simply modify the underlying list during the iteration.

ArrayList defines its behaviour when you attempt to interact with one from multiple threads as **undefined**. ArrayList is free to throw CoModEx, or not, and you will in fact find that its behaviour depends on so many factors, it might as well involve the phase of the moon: It'll depend on which song is playing in your music player, which OS you're on, whether the code was hotspotted or not, whether that add so happens to push up the capacity, and other stuff. If you write code that in any way or form depends on behaviour of a type like ArrayList in the face of interacting with it from multiple threads, that code is by definition buggy, and yet buggy in a way that cannot be reliably tested. i.e. horrible, it turns your software into a mess that fails all the time and yet cannot be tested for; your dev team will spend entire weeks on wild goose chases to find these bugs.

**There is no way to unit test the behaviour of types under multi-thread interop**. At best a unit test can try to make things fail. It cannot guarantee it, and in fact it is not hard to write code that works **every time** on hardware platform A and fails quite often on platform B.

There is no good direct solution to dealing with code that has broken multi-thread code. Just the pithy and mostly useless 'well, do not write that kind of code'. There is a reason folks use the DB as sole vehicle of concurrent state (because it has abstractions like SERIALIZABLE transaction level, retries, and transactions to deal with it), and message busses.

Comment: I agree that "There is no need to involve threads to do this" . But the problem is that the ConcurrentException happens very rare in existing logic since the method which handles/process Arraylist is not synchronized and multiple threads access it at same time (read & update list at same time). To simulate that specific scenario, I have to go with multi-threaded Unit tests

Comment: As I said, you can't fix a race condition by writing a test for it. You just.. have to fix it, blind. Any test for this is likely to NOT report a test failure even if the code you're testing has this bug in it.